# Mysql query always returns empty value

Tags: mysql, return

This is my code:

```
$pass = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM acc WHERE account_id = '122' LIMIT 1;");
$p = mysql_fetch_object($pass);
$passwd = ( ( $p->password != "" ) ? $p->password : "empty" );
```

Then I'm doing `echo $passwd;` and it's always is retuning the "empty" string.

Of course the row with `account_id` 122 exists.

What is wrong with that?

Comment: You're selecting row where account_id is 122, not 133. Typo?

Comment: is this a facepalm or a double facepalm?

Comment: @Mike Nakis I've just facepalm'd while reading your comment.

Comment: @NiklasLindblad Typo, updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `acc` WHERE `account_id`='122'") or die(mysql_error());
while($data=mysql_fetch_object($query)){
$pass = $data->password;
}
echo $pass
```

You should now be able to acces all fields from that row including the password field.

Comment: You've misquoted `account_id`.

Answer (score 0):

what if you change

```
$passwd = ( ( $p->password != "" ) ? $p->password : "empty" );
```

to

```
$passwd = (empty($p->password)) ? $p->password : "empty" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the semi-colon at the end of your query. Why do you have a limit 1? `acc` should be unique on `account_id` as having multiple passwords for the same account should be impossible.

```
$pass = mysql_query("SELECT `password` FROM acc WHERE account_id = '122'");
```

As @shawn pointed out if your `account_id` is indeed a number it's better not to rely on the implicit character to number conversion. Though it doesn't actually matter it's not good practice.